# Unable to put session in Laravel Vue using Axios

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to create an endpoint and send the data to then endpoint and requesting it later within the controller method. As the input value changes, it fires axios put method and pass the updated `perPage` data to an endpoint, I am getting a successful response, with status 200 in the console log, but the value isn't being updated or created in the sessions. I just don't know what am I missing here. Please throw some light here. Thanks!

Web

```
Route::put('/set-per-page', [UserController::class, 'setPerPage'])->name('set.per_page');
```

Controller

```
public function setPerPage(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->put('perPage', $request->perPage);
    return session('perPage');
}
```

Component

```
<template>
    <input-group inline>
        <input-select v-model="perPage" placeholder="Per Page">
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </input-select>
    </input-group>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            perPageData: {
                type: Number
            }
        },

        data() {
            return {
                perPage: this.perPageData
            }
        },

        watch: {
            perPage: {
                handler: function() {
                    axios.put(route('set.per_page', { per_page: this.per_page })).then((response)=>{ this.$inertia.reload({ only: ['usersData'] }), console.log(response) })
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `$request->perPage` is actually set? Since no `name` attribute is present on the input (it's no form POST) it might be necessary to access the `perPage` attribute via `$request->input('perPage')`.

Comment: Mate, thanks for the revert, I have posted a solution, incase anyone gets stuck here in the future, please have a look if you get time! Thanks anyway :D

Comment: Have updated the code enclosed within the `perPage` watcher, to reload only `usersData` as a response, whenever the `perPage` value is updated.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was, we cant use `sessions()` within `public function __construct()` so it was unable to get the value from the session. As per the current setup, with a minor work around the problem was solved.

Using an inline middleware, we can hook into the request's routing, so that we have full access to the session.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {

        $this->perPage = session()->get('perPage', $this->perPage);

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```